# How to use interface within an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have this:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface Line {
    vertix1: Point;
    vertix2: Point;
}

let v1: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
let v2: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
let line: Line = {vertix1: v1, vertix2: v2};
```

How can I define `line` directly without defining `v1` and `v2`? I tried and that, obviously, did not work:

```
let line1: Line = {
    vertix1: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 },
    vertix2: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using a class which implements an interface.

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface ILine {
    vertix1: Point;
    vertix2: Point;
}

class Point implements IPoint {
  x: int;
  y: int;

  constructor(x: int, y: int) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Line implments ILine {
  vertix1: Point;
  vertix2: Point;

  constructor(vertix1: Point, vertix2: Point) {
    this.vertix1 = vertix1;
    this.vertix2 = vertix2;
  }
}
let v1: Point = new Point(1,2);
let v2: Point = new Point(1,2);
let line: Line = new Line(v1,v2);
```

You could also create the points in the constructor.  Not sure if this answers your question but hope it helps.

```
let line: Line = new Line(new Point(1,2), new Point(1,2))
```

Comment: I had this simplified for the concept. In practice, what if for example, this is my initialState for a redux application?!

Comment: @Kousha how is your initial state set? I am assuming the initial state gets passed in or you are setting it, correct?  Not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: That's just an example. I'm saying I want to have an object defined using an interface. I don't want it to be a class. Or is that what it should be in Typescript? I'm very new to this.

Comment: @Kousha I think you are misunderstand what an interface and class are. An interface is just a contract which says here are all the functions and/or variables you must have if you say you are implementing me.  The only way you can implement an interface is with a class. So it is invalid when you write `vertix1: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 }` because Point isn't a class...it is an interface. If you want to create a new type called Point, you have to create a class and define a constructor so that the new type called Point knows its properties.

Comment: I understand that, and that confused me a bit first, but on their own official documentations, they use interfaces for objects: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: That is interesting. Normally you wouldn't use an interface like that, but you are right...it looks like that is exactly how they are using it in the documentation. I think the catch is that you would have to use it like this: `vertix1: Point;` so define it first and then set its properties, `vertix1.x = 1;` and `vertix1.y = 2;`. Which seems totally wrong to me to be able to create a new object without class instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

It would be just :

```
let line1: Line = {
    vertix1: { x: 1, y: 2 },
    vertix2: { x: 1, y: 2 },
}
```

classes can easily be skipped thanksfully.